# Python subprocess not passing curly brackets as arguments on Windows

Tags: python

At the Windows command line, the following behaves exactly as expected:

```
C:\> c:\cygwin\bin\printf "<%s>\n" "{foo}"
{foo}
```

From inside a native win32 Python instance, however, the curly brackets are stripped:

```
>>> subprocess.Popen(['c:\\cygwin\\bin\\printf', '<%s>\n', '{foo}'],
...                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].rstrip('\n')
'foo'
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `pipes.quote()` to resolve this issue:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html#pipes.quote

Alternatively, if you're on python3, checkout shlex.quotes(): http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#module-shlex

Comment: The docs you linked to have a big pink "Deprecated since version 2.7" box. That being said, I'm not sure what you're _supposed_ to use instead in 2.7 (or in 3.0-3.2, which have neither this nor `shlex.quote`)…

Comment: This does indeed work. That said, I'm very disturbed that it works -- the `shell=False` use of subprocess.Popen, after all, is supposed to avoid any non-literal treatment of argument characters.

Comment: ...also, while this works for the printf case given here, when I use it for a filename, the backslashes are being treated as path element separators, not escape characters. *sigh*.

Comment: Yeah, there should really be a better alternative, but I'm afraid I haven't come across any as of yet.